# Two dice are thrown

Tags: probability

A die is numbered in such a way that its faces show the number 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6. It is thrown two times and the total score in two throws is noted. Complete the following table which gives a few values of the total score on the two throws:
[image]

What is the probability that the total score is
(i) even?   (ii)    6?  (iii)   at least 6?

The answer to this question is:-
Here is the table (completed)

```
+  1    2   2   3   3   6
1  2    3   3   4   4   7
2  3    4   4   5   5   8
2  3    4   4   5   5   8
3  4    5   5   6   6   9
3  4    5   5   6   6   9
6  7    8   8   9   9   12
```

(i)18/36
(ii)4/36
(iii)15/36

Can someone please explain me how to complete this table?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the position $i+1,j+1$ you put the sum of the $i$-th number in the first column and the $j$-th number in the first row.

The first row has a $+$ and the possible values on the faces of the first dice. The first column has a $+$ (the same $+$) and the possible values on the faces of the second dice. They are just adding these numbers for all possibilities.